# in NetworkX update node value

Tags: python, networkx

I have a graph made in NetworkX. In the graph there are saved some (x,y) positions of a shape. I want to keep in the graph the normal (x,y) positions found in a shape recognition script but when I draw the graph I want to draw it at (x, height-y) positions, where height is the height of the picture. This is needed because if I draw the graph with the normal (x,y) positions, the shape is shown all the way around. So here is the code I wrote:

```
#ap is the array containing the (x,y) positions of the shape. x=ap[0][0], y=ap[0][1] and so on.
pe = nx.Graph()
pe.add_node('p1', posxy=(ap[0][0], ap[0][1]))
pe.add_node('p2', posxy=(ap[1][0], ap[1][1]))
pe.add_node('p3', posxy=(ap[2][0], ap[2][1]))
pe.add_node('p4', posxy=(ap[3][0], ap[3][1]))
pe.add_node('p5', posxy=(ap[4][0], ap[4][1]))
pe.add_cycle(['p1','p2','p3','p4','p5'])
positions = nx.get_node_attributes(pe, 'posxy')
nx.draw(pe, positions, labels=positions, font_size=8, font_weight='bold', node_color='yellow', alpha=0.5)
```

when I try to modify the variable `positions` it doesn't work. I tried to do something like: `height-'posxy'[1]` to update only the `y` component of `posxy`, but it does not work. It returns this error: `unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'`, so I don't know how to update the attribute `'posxy'` for the nodes.

How can I do it?

Any help is apreciated.

Comment: "it does not work" - be more specific. Errors (provide full traceback)? Unexpected outputs (provide inputs and expected and actual outputs)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression

```
height - 'posxy'[1]
```

Would evaluate to

```
height - 'o'
```

hence the error you are seeing.

According to the [documentation](http://networkx.lanl.gov/archive/networkx-1.5/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.get_node_attributes.html?highlight=get_node_attributes#networkx.classes.function.get_node_attributes), `positions` will be a dictionary `{node: posxy, ...}`.

`posxy` is a tuple, e.g. `(1, 2)`, which is immutable, so you can't simply assign to one of the values (e.g. `posxy[1] = ...`); you will get a an error here too:

```
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

Instead, process all of them, creating a new tuple for each position using e.g. a dictionary comprehension:

```
positions = {k: (v[0], height - v[1]) for k, v in positions.items()}
```

Comment: this is exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot. I rate it as accepted answer and +1.